# "Hold accountable" or "Be charged"?

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

Can I use the idiom "Hold accountable" without putting someone's name as is required before the word **accountable**, like instead of this: **hold someone accountable (for something)**, it would be like this: **hold accountable (for something)**.

I need it to be in that form because I defined who is that someone as a pronoun:

> They have to hold accountable for their actions.

If that is not acceptable then is **to be charged** considered a good replacement? (But without the **with**)

> They have to be charged for their actions.

The meaning I intend, is: There is a group of people who are responsible for doing a conspiracy against someone named X. X discovered their conspiracy, so she says that they have to ____ for their actions/conspiracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first version is almost okay, but a slight change needs to be made:

> They have to **be held** accountable for their actions.

---

The second version may not have the same meaning. Being held accountable doesn't necessarily mean being charged with a crime; in fact, it often doesn't.

Accountability can be moral as well as criminal.

Children who have done something wrong are generally held accountable by being given a curfew or some kind of punishment. They don't have charges brought against them.